# How to Set Alpha or opacity in old view only before addsubView

Tags: iphone, opacity, alpha

I don't know, How to set old view in interface to decrease alpha in old view only

not decrease New view

i have this function

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    testView * subTestview = [[testView alloc]initWithNibName:@"TestView" bundle:nil];
    subTestview.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, subTestview.view.frame.size.width,
                                        subTestview.view.frame.size.height);
    subTestview.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
    self.view.alpha = 0.3f;
    [self.view addSubview:subTestview.view];
}
```

when i use "self.view.alpha = 0.3f", it decrease alpha of all view

Help me please

Thank you

Ton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should make another parent view. Put your testView on it. Put your subTestview on it also independently(not as a subview of testView, but as a subview of parent view). Try to set alpha of your testView after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code to add view controller as subview in current view

**CurrentViewController.m**

```
PopUpViewController *popUpViewController = [[PopUpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopUpViewController" bundle:nil];
popUpViewController.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.9f];
popUpViewController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview: popUpViewController.view];
[self addChildViewController: popUpViewController];
```